# UDP Socket code in Clojure CLR

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, clojure, enums

I'm trying to figure out proper syntax for interop with .Net System.Net.Sockets. My problem is the enumeration parts of the arguments. Here is the equivalent code in c#:

`Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)`

In clojure-clr I'm trying the following:

```
(System.Net.Sockets.Socket. (AddressFamily/InterNetwork) (SocketType/Dgram) (ProtocolType/Udp))
```

I'm getting CompilerException.InvalidOperationException.
I reviewed https://github.com/clojure/clojure-clr/wiki/Working-with-enums regarding the enum but not understanding it.

I've also tried:

```
(System.Net.Sockets.Socket. (.InterNetwork AddressFamily) (.Dgram SocketType) (.Udp ProtocolType))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
(import [System.Net.Sockets Socket AddressFamily SocketType ProtocolType])
(Socket. AddressFamily/InterNetwork SocketType/Dgram ProtocolType/Udp)
```